# Can a method that does not return a value contain 0 formal parameters?

Tags: java, methods, void

Can a method that does not return a value contain 0 formal parameters?
I understand this means that there won't be any actual parameter either but I'm just wondering if this is correct in any case?

Comment: This is rather trivial to try. Why do you think you can't? Why do you think you can?

Comment: well of course you can due to the fact that with methods that don't return values they are still able to run but they won't necessarily return anything to outside to where it is being called from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it can.

What about a function, for example, that prints the current time?

A more concrete case in Java is System.gc() which suggests a garbage collection.

The Java language doesn't attempt to make rather pointless restrictions.